# Printing entire contents of InfoPath multi line text field

Tags: infopath

I have a InfoPath form with 9 different views and when the user fills all the views and submit then it is saved to the list. I have created an extra view for printing all the information on single form. This extra view is pointed in a page by adding InfoPath web part to it. Everything works well except multiline text boxes cut-off the text and shows blank. Only some information is showed and rest is blank in multi line box. I tried different forums in google and made the height auto and text font to Ariel, but the issue still persists. 
I am using SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath 2010. Can some one suggest me options to over come this.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion might be to simply direct the users to the print view of the InfoPath form with a button (or similar) on your current web page that opens the form in InfoPath - print view, and they can print directly from InfoPath. I'm assuming you've already tested that all the fields show correctly when using the print view directly from InfoPath?

Might be a suitable work around?